# Performance of two meteor apps on one database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I've created simple todo app from meteor.com website. Let's call it 'project A'.

Then duplicated directory with project. Let's call it 'project B'.
I've started project A normally.

After that I've started project B on port 3456 and connect to project's A database through env variables.

The **problem is**:

- when I add todo in project B, changes appears immidietly in project A.
- When I add todo in project A, in project B changes appears after few seconds.

**Question is: Why?**

There are two equally the same projects connected to the same database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because oplog tailing is disabled.

When there's no oplog tailing, Meteor uses "poll-and-diff" strategy that execute mongodb queries every 10 seconds and then do a diff to see if some data changed.

To solve it, you can activate oplog tailing this way: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver#oplogobservedriver-in-production